# Docker doesn't apply changes to daemon.json

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have created the file /etc/docker/daemon.json on ubuntu with the following contents:

```
{
  "ipv6": false
}
```

Afterward I rebooted the machine and docker is still looking for ipv6 addresses, giving me the following error on `docker swarm init --advertise address enp0s3`:

```
Error response from daemon: interface enp0s3 has more than one IPv6 address (2a00:c98:2060:a000:1:0:1d1e:ca75 and fe80::a00:27ff:fe7e:d9c4)
```

¿How do I apply the changes to the daemon so I stop encountering this error? I can't advertise an specific ip address since the machine is using dhcp.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you apply the change and restart the deamon on _all_ docker swarm machines?

Comment: @KamilCuk I saved the file and rebooted the machine so that should restart all docker machines, doesnt it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved using the following command:

```
sudo docker swarm init --advertise-address "$(ip addr show $MAIN_ETH_INTERFACE | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)"
```

This way I don't need to specify an ipv4 address.